# CSOM File object ID property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom

What is the correct way to initialize or call File obj ID property? I don't see it as a default object property. I tried calling via:

- File.ListItemAllFields["ID"]

That failed. I did notice the following property:

- File.ListId

I assumed that was not the File ID, but list ID containing File?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `file.UniqueId` property

Comment: Thanks, I overlooked that property!